# Saving pyspark dataframe from azure databricks to azure data lake in a specific folder created dynamically

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory, databricks-community-edition

I am doing some ETL process in Azure.

```
1. Source data is in Azure data lake
2. Processing it in Azure databricks
3. Loading the output dataframe in Azure data lake to a specific folder 
   considering Current year / Month / date and then file name in csv format.
```

I am stuck in 3rd step -

```
1. Tried loading the dataframe to mnt location
   outPath = '/dbfs/mnt/abcd/<outputfoldername>/' + cy_year + "/" + 
   cy_month + "/" + cy_date + "/"

df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").opt 
 ion("header","true").csv(outPath)
```

This is saving data to DBFS but not to ADLS as suggested by many links over internet.

```
2. Tried working like - 
   spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storage account 
   name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<<ACCESS KEY")

  output_container_path = "abfss://<container- 
  name>@salesdetails.dfs.core.windows.net/<dir path>"

  df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").option("header", 
  "true").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(output_container_path)
```

This is saving into data into ADLS but into 4 files. 3 are supported ones. I want only one final file name example abc.csv

```
3. Tried with pandas dataframe which gives us flexibility to name the 
   file name but here we will need specific folder name which is not the 
   case with me.
```

> Please assist at the earliest. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have your tried mounting your ADLS into a mount in databricks? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/mounts

Comment: yes, that's how I am doing transformation in ADB but after transformation while saving back to ADLS - I am facing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Follow these steps:**

1.Mount your storage account with azure data lake gen 2 as per [MS_Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/mounts).

```
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "f4dab6c8-5009-4857xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret":"3GF8Q~3ZGkgflxxxxxxxxx",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/72f988bfxxxxxxx/oauth2/token"}

dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://demo123@vamblob.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/abcd11",
  extra_configs = configs)
```

[image]

2.Configure your storage account and read the Source data is in Azure data lake.

```
df11 = spark.read.format("csv").load("abfss://<container>@<Storage_acccount>.dfs.core.windows.net/")

display(df11)
```

[image]

**Sample_Code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import year, month, dayofmonth
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
year = now.year
month = now.month
day = now.day

folder12 = "/mnt/abcd1/{}/{}/{}/output.csv".format(year, month, day)

# write the dataframe into the  folder in CSV format
df1.write.option("header", "true").csv(folder12, mode="overwrite")
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]